# mySQL JOIN query for users with 0 assigned records

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, voter and user. I want to show all users with the total # of assigned voter records next to their user info.

At this point, this query kind of works --  it shows the total for users who have any number of records assigned, but it DOESN'T show users who have 0 records assigned in the voter table.

Voter records are assigned to a user with the field voter.owner. Here's what I have currently:

```sql
SELECT u.id
    ,u.admin
    ,u.active
    ,u.name
    ,u.email
    ,u.last
    ,if(count(v.owner) is NULL,'0',count( v.owner )) as assigned 
from user u 
left join voter v 
    on u.id = v.owner 
where u.cid = '$cid' 
order by u.id asc
```

Any advice on how to show all users, even ones that don't own and voter records?

Comment: You should be careful with MySQL reserved words as table name (like USER), or escape them correctly. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: can we see some sample data from both tables? To me, this looks like a proper left join (keeping rows from user, even when not matched in voter). You might try `GROUP`ing your results

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A Left-Join is the wrong approach for this Problem.
The solution is to use a sub-select like so:

```
SELECT `user.id`, `user.admin`, `user.active`, `user.name`, `user.email`, `user.last`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voter WHERE `user.id` = voter.owner)
FROM `user` 
WHERE user.cid = '$cid'
ORDER BY `user.id` ASC
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great - now I realize that a subquery is the way to go for this problem.

Comment: Nothing wrong with left join here. OTOH mysql does not handle push-predicates in sub-queries very well.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(count(v.owner) is NULL,'0',count( v.owner )) as assigned
```

should be...

```
SUM(if(v.owner is NULL,0,1) as assigned
```